# jQuery selector works but has no proper effect

Tags: jquery

I have a runtime generated div (by js) with the following structure:

```
$('.display_section').html(
'<div class="edit_container">' +
     '<h1>Edit member</h1>' +
  '<div class="edit_split">' +
    '<div class="edit_label">First Name:</div>' +
    '<div id="edit_first_name" class="edit_attr"><input type="text" id="edit_first_name" value="' + edit_member_first_name + '"/></div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="edit_split">' +
    '<div class="edit_label">Last Name:</div>' +
    '<div id="edit_last_name" class="edit_attr"><input type="text" id="edit_last_name" value="' + edit_member_last_name + '"/></div>' +
  '</div>'(...)
```

After the generation I do a validation with the following code:

```
function checkFieldsEdit() 
{   
     if ($('#edit_first_name').val().trim().length === 0)     $('#edit_first_name').addClass('required'); 
     if ($('#edit_last_name').val().trim().length === 0)      $('#edit_last_name').addClass('required');
```

Somewhy this validation doesn't do anything. Even if a textbox is empty, its class never changes. 
Since the script does nothing, its not a surprise that the following function returns with true:

```
if (!$('.display_section').children().hasClass('required')) {
        return true;
} else {
        return false;
}
```

The interesting thing is that, I use the similar function (named checkFields, which checks the new member section's text inputs) on a different place but the same page. I tried to modify the content to

```
<input type="text" id="edit_first_name" value="" class="required">(...)
```

by using the chrome runtime element editor (or whatever its name) to see what happens. And then if I run the following jQuery code in the console

```
!$('.display_section').children().hasClass('required')
```

the result is a big surprise for me: true. Since I modified its class to "required", it should return with false. Even if I used

```
!$('.edit_container').children().hasClass('required')
```

the result was true. When I ran `$('.required')` on the console, it listed one element, which one was modified by me before. But still true. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you in advance.

### **EDIT:**

Duplicated ID problem has been solved, but the main problem is still there :/ when I modify the text input's class runtime to "required", the console gives the same results: `!$('.edit_container').children().hasClass('required')
true
!$('.display_section').children().hasClass('required')
true`

Comment: [IDs must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Comment: you have duplicate ID's man

Comment: wow, such a mistake lol. Thanks guys. But I still have the problem, when I modify the class runtime to "required", the console gives the same results: `!$('.display_section').children().hasClass('required')
true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it works

```
 if ($('#edit_first_name').val() == '')     $('#edit_first_name').addClass('required'); 
 if ($('#edit_last_name').val() == '')      $('#edit_last_name').addClass('required');
```